# Telerik RadPaneGroup problem

Tags: wpf, telerik, docking, raddocking

I use Telerik Rad Controls for WPF 2009.3.1314. Here is my layout:

```
<raddock:RadDocking x:Name="radDocking">
            <raddock:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
            </raddock:RadDocking.DocumentHost>

            <raddock:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedLeft">
                <raddock:RadPaneGroup>
                    <raddock:RadPane Header="Screens" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ScreensRadPaneHeaderTemplate}">
                        <radnav:RadTreeView x:Name="radTreeViewScreens" />
                    </raddock:RadPane>
                </raddock:RadPaneGroup>
            </raddock:RadSplitContainer>

            <raddock:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedRight">
                <raddock:RadPaneGroup>
                    <raddock:RadPane Header="Object Explorer" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ObjectExplorerRadPaneHeaderTemplate}">
                    </raddock:RadPane>
                </raddock:RadPaneGroup>
            </raddock:RadSplitContainer>

            <raddock:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedBottom">
                <raddock:RadPaneGroup>
                    <raddock:RadPane Header="Events" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource EventsRadPaneHeaderTemplate}">
                    </raddock:RadPane>

                    <raddock:RadPane Header="Errors" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ErrorsRadPaneHeaderTemplate}">
                    </raddock:RadPane>

                    <raddock:RadPane Header="Server Explorer" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ServerExplorerRadPaneHeaderTemplate}">
                    </raddock:RadPane>
                </raddock:RadPaneGroup>
            </raddock:RadSplitContainer>
        </raddock:RadDocking>
```

It's all great, but when I hide left RadPane and click on it again (to show it) it doesn't appeared until I click on anything else (to lost focus, may be not focus but anything state).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I upgrade to new version.